# Accessing an appsettings value in a class library from another project

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a Core project with this appsetting:

```
"Connections": 
{
"DBName": "ConnectionString"
}
```

It is defined in a class file like this:

```
public class Connections
{
    public string "DBName" { get; set; }
}
```

It is injected in the startup.cs method like this:

```
   services.Configure<Connections>(Configuration.GetSection("Connections"));
```

So now I need to access that value in a class library within the same solution.

But the Connections class is not recognized in the other project.  How do I access that value in this class library?

```
 internal static class DataStuff
 {
    ...  

     static DataStuff(Connections stuff) 
     {
        ...
     }
 }
```

Comment: You could just inject or read from `IConfiguration` in class `DataStuff`

Comment: I'm already doing that in the startup.cs file.  How do I access that in the other project?  Nothing from there is recognized.

Comment: Could the ability to __share__ an `appsettings.json` file be helpful in your use-case?

Comment: I shared the relevant setting.  The actual file is very large and filled with other settings just like that.

Comment: Not sure we are on the same page here: Is it feasible to collect the settings that are shared across projects in one common file? That specific file can be shared.

btw, when replying to a comment you have the option to "mention" the author (in my case @ShaiCohen). I've found it useful.

Comment: Make sure you are referencing that library, if you're on VS, go to the references list, then click 'Add Reference', it should be there after you build your class library. Then, you write `using [LIB_NAME];`